# jQuery - iterate through all elements with class and change their style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is supposed to be simple, but I'm running into multiple problems. First of all, I don't know how to get all elements of a class and change their display. I found the `.each` method with this sample code:

```
$('.classname').each(function(index) {
        alert(index);
});
```

What do I need instead of the alert to change the display property of an element from 'none' to block'?

The second problem is, the class name is gathered from a hidden field. Let's name this variable `service`. When I try to replace the '.classname' with '.'+service I get an error saying 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .'.

So the actual code would be something like:

```
var service=$('#service').val();
$('.'+service).each(function(index) {
        alert(index);
});
```

I'm sure this can't be complicated but I can't figure it out.

Any alternative solution is of course welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
var service=$('#service').val();
$('.'+service).show(); // roughly equivalent to .css('display', 'block');
```

However, as the documentation for `show` points out, the method returns the matched elements `display` property to it's previous state. To explicitly change the `display` style property to `block`, use [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
$('.' + service).css("display", "block");
```

Comment: That works for showing the elements but I'm still getting the syntax error. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @robert: Are you sure the issue is with this code? It is syntactically correct

Comment: Maybe the error lies in whatever value you're getting from `$('#service').val()`. Could you give an example of the value inside `#service`? For the above code to work, it should just be a single, legal class name.

Answer (score 0):

try fadeIn() and fadeOut()

```
var service=$("#service").val();
$("."+service).fadeIn();
```